# Why is IF statement executing on itself

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-nano

```
x = 5;
Serial.println (x);

if (x == 0);
    {
      //stuff in this IF keeps happening why ?
      //Iam too stupid ?
    }
```

Comment: the `if` statement must be executed to evaluate the condition. if the condition is true the following command or block of commands is executed. your command after the `if` is `;` (empty command)

Answer (score 3):

You have a rogue semi-colon.

Splitting your code up on the end of statements you get:

```
1. x = 5; 
2. Serial.println (x);
3. if (x == 0);
4. { // stuff }
```

With the semi-colon after the `if` it terminates the `if` before the opening block `{`, and that block becomes a completely separate statement detached from the `if`.

Comment: Yeah, most of us have been bitten by this one. I wish C/C++ compilers would flag this `if (condition);` form with a warning as it is very likely a mistake, and is certainly bad coding practice even if intentional. (Same for `if (a=b)`. Valid, but bad practice.)

Comment: @DuncanC They can. GCC has the flag `-Wempty-body`: "Warn if an empty body occurs in an "if", "else" or "do while" statement.  This warning is also enabled by -Wextra."

Comment: It should be on by default.

Comment: Hell, I'd even argue it should be flagged as an error. Anybody who deliberately writes a "side-effect only" `if` statement should be shot. :)

Comment: You can turn it on in preferences in the Aduino IDE.  `/home/matt/Arduino/sketch_mar30a/sketch_mar30a.ino:5:14: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]`